# Question on a proof of Ramsey's Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

How do some Ramsey's Theorem proofs get to proving the inequality:

$R(s, t) \le R(s − 1, t) + R(s, t − 1)$

I get how the result shows, in the end, that there is a finite $R(s,t)$ but what's the intuition behind that step. In other words how does one think of such an inequality?

Comment: Direct induction. Pick a vertex, consider the red/blue degree of it.

Answer (score 3):

> Recall how we prove $R(3,3)=6$. We fix a point $p$ of $K_6$ in which all edges are randomly and independently colored by red or blue.
>
> There are $5$ edges out of $p$. By pigeonhole principle, at least $3$ or them are in the same color, say red. We denote the endpoints of these three edges distinct from $p$ by $p_1,p_2,p_3$.
>
> Apparently, either $p_1,p_2,p_3$ form a blue triangle, or there is an edge, say $p_1p_2$ is red. Then $pp_1$, $pp_2$ and $p_1p_2$ form a red triangle. Therefore, we can either get a red triangle or a blue triangle in $K_6$, so $R(3,3)\leq 6$. In particular, we can find a counterexample in $K_5$, so $R(3,3)=6$.

The proof of such inequality is similar. Again, we fix a point $p$ of $K_n$ whose edges are randomly and independently colored by red or blue, where $$n=R(s,t-1)+R(s-1,t).$$

We then partition the neighbors (of course all the vertices in $K_n$ other than $p$) into two sets: $A$ and $B$ such that the edges between $p$ and vertices in $A$ are colored in red and the edges between $p$ and vertices in $A$ are colored in blue. As we can see, either 
\begin{equation}
|A|\geq R(s-1,t)\quad\text{or}\quad|B|\geq R(s,t-1). 
\end{equation}

If $|A|\geq R(s-1,t)$, consider the clique induced by $A$. Such clique either contains a red $K_{s-1}$, which, together with $p$, form a red $K_s$, or a blue $K_t$. Similarly, if $|B|\geq R(s,t-1)$, then the clique induced by $B$ either contains a blue $K_{t-1}$ or a red $K_s$. That is, we can either find a red $K_s$ or a blue $K_t$ in such $K_n$, hence
$$R(s,t)\leq R(s,t-1)+R(s-1,t).$$

> **P.S.** Let
>   $$f(s,t)=\binom{s+t-2}{s-1}$$
>   By Pascal's triangle, we have 
>   $$\binom{s+t-2}{s-1}=\binom{s+t-3}{s-2}+\binom{s+t-3}{s-1}.$$
>   That is, 
>   $$f(s,t)=f(s-1,t)+f(s,t-1).$$
>   In particular, we have $R(2,t)=t=f(2,t)$ and $R(s,2)=s=f(s,2)$. Such inequality tells us 
>   $$R(s,t)\leq f(s,t)=\binom{s+t-2}{s-1},$$
>   giving an upper bound for the Ramsey number.
>
> But this bound is not tight for large $s$ and $t$ , say if $s=t$, this bound becomes 
>   $$R(s,s)\leq\binom{2s-2}{s-1}\sim\left(\frac{2s-2}{s-1}\right)^{s-1}=2^{s-1}.$$
>   It grows exponentially as $s$ increases.

Comment: Could you explain how we decided that $n=R(s,t-1)+R(s-1,t)$?

Comment: @rohit_wason Here we just want an upper bound. We set some specific value for $n$ to see whether a random $2$-coloring of $K_n$ will yield either a red $K_s$ or a blue $K_t$. If it does, then $R(s,t)\leq n$. By setting $n=R(s,t-1)+R(s-1,t)$, we obtain the desired property.

Comment: thanks. So basically it's due to one of the creative moments in the mathematician's work, that this value of n "sticks", correct? My question is not in the validity of the step, rather in the intuition behind it. And it seems like there must have been days' worth of work on someone's (Ramsey? Erdos?) part, to have come up with this simple recursion that works.